# Error running Lifecycle Configuration for SageMaker Studio Notebook

Tags: amazon-sagemaker-studio

I am trying to create a Lifecycle Configuration for Studio notebooks with the below code for restarting the server.

```
#!/bin/bash
set -eux
nohup supervisorctl -c /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf restart jupyterlabserver
```

I get an error saying **nohup: failed to run command 'supervisorctl': No such file or directory**. But the same when I run on the terminal it runs properly. What am I doing wrong?